# Compiling CoffeeScript from Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript

Im looking for a way to compile all of my coffeescript files, currently in individual files such as features.coffee // scroll.coffee etc etc, in to one main outputed .js file.

Im using an application.coffee file at current to act as the main file. Ive imported my various files using:

```
  #= require features.coffee 
  #= require scroll.coffee
```

However when Im outputting the application.coffee to application.js on the code from within the application.coffee is outputting and not that of the imported files

Im assuming that coffeescript imports are not native features and that some sort of plugin will be needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked grunt.js out? It could help here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually merge the source files into a main script file ( aka concatenate them ), then compile to JavaScript. You have not specified what you are working with, but in node.js, the `require` function only executes an external script ( to put it very simply ), it does not place the source code into current file as you seem to be expecting.

There are many tools on the network to concatenate your source code into a single main script - just [google around](https://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript%20concatenate%20source%20files) and find what suits you best.